# PySide6 QTree update value of specific row/column

Tags: pyside6

I created a simple tree and a button. What I want to do is increase the cat's power by 1 each time I press the button. Assuming that I already know cat's position (root -> second item -> second item), how can I update the progress bar in `increaseValue`?

[image]

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Qt, Slot
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QProgressBar, QPushButton, \
    QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

data = {"Canidae": {"Wolf": 70, "Fox": 40, "Dog": 30},
        "Felidae": {"Tiger": 100, "Cat": 20}};

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

tree = QTreeWidget()
tree.setColumnCount(2)
tree.setHeaderLabels(["Animal", "Power"])
tree.setColumnWidth(0, 150)
tree.setColumnWidth(1, 200)

items = []
for key, values in data.items():
    item = QTreeWidgetItem([key])
    for key2, values2 in values.items():
        pb = QProgressBar();
        pb.setRange(0, 100);
        pb.setValue(values2);
        pb.setAutoFillBackground(True);
        child = QTreeWidgetItem([key2])

        item.addChild(child)
        tree.setItemWidget(child, 1, pb);
    items.append(item)

@Slot()
def increaseValue():
    print("Button clicked");

tree.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)
tree.expandAll();

testButton = QPushButton("Test");
testButton.clicked.connect(increaseValue)

layout = QVBoxLayout();
layout.addWidget(tree);
layout.addWidget(testButton);

window = MainWindow()
window.resize(400, 300)
window.show()

dummy = QWidget()
dummy.setLayout(layout)
window.setCentralWidget(dummy)

app.exec()
```

Comment: I [already suggested you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77406800/2001654) to use a delegate, which is also extremely useful as it will automatically update the progress bar if you properly use the index data. Why do you want to use an item widget? Also, the `@Slot` decorator is almost always unnecessary, and it can only work for methods of QObject based classes, so your usage there is completely useless.